# Is the limit $\lim_{x\to y^-}\sum_{\{n:r_n\in(x,y)\}}\frac{1}{2^n}$ equal zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I believe that the limit below is zero, but I am not quite sure why. Here we have $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$
  is an enumeration of rationals. I am assuming the reason is because as $x\rightarrow y^{-}$
  the set $\{n:r_n\in(x,y)\}$
  is an empty set or it doesn't contain any rational. But I am also thinking if $\delta>0$
  then the limit from the left means $y-\delta<x<y$
 , hence $x<y$
  and we know that between any two reals there is at least finitely many rationals. Which make the sum below doesn't equal to zero. Any help is appreciated.

$$\lim_{x\to y^{-}}\sum_{\{n:r_n\in(x,y)\}}\frac{1}{2^n} \overset{?}{=}0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, between any two reals there are *infinitely* many rationals...

Now, when $x$ goes to $y-$, your $n$ (of $r_n$) increases. The reason is that given a $k$, we will eventually cross the $k$th rational number as we go to $y$, or we'll never meet him... In any case, after $x$ approaches $y$ close enough, only large numbers $n$ will contribute to the sum.

Now, just notice that $\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2^k}$ and that goes to $0$...