# How to prove this function is left continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $\{r_n\}$ denote the set of all rational numbers in the interval $J:[a,b]$ and define $\alpha:J\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\alpha(t)=\sum\limits_{n:r_n<t}\frac{1}{2^n}$.Then show that $\alpha$ is left-continuous.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

I want to show by the definition:$\lim_{x\to t-}\alpha(x)=\alpha(t)$.

That means $\forall {x_n}\to t(x_n<t)$ I should guarantee that $\forall \epsilon>0 ,\exists N ,s.t.\forall n>N,|\alpha(x_n)-\alpha(t)|<\epsilon$.

Intuitively I should argue that when $x_n$ is close to $t$,$\alpha(x_n)$ is close to $\alpha(t)$, which means I should prove that no matter how many '$n$'s there are in between(definitely infinite), the sum $\sum\limits_{n:x_n \leq r_n<t}\frac{1}{2^n}$ is controllable. And I think for any $\epsilon$ I can pick a $N$ such that $\sum\limits_{n \geq N}\frac{1}{2^n}<\epsilon$.

But then I can't get any further...Is my direction right, if so how can I get further? Or are there other approaches? Any help and hints will be appreciated!

Best regards!

Comment: Note that the system automatically finds potentially related questions (on the right hand side of the page).  I think [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216792/is-the-limit-lim-x-to-y-sum-nr-n-inx-y-frac12n-equal-zero?rq=1) pretty much answers your question.

Comment: @David: Thanks it really does.Next time I should check it first...